# Get Data from Social Bakers API

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to get the data from social bakers API for Facebook but getting an error while requesting it

The error says:

```
Authorization is not valid.
```

Here is my code:

```
import json 
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1

token = 'mytoken'
headers = { 'Authorization' : 'Token ' + token }
r = requests.get('https://api.socialbakers.com/0/facebook/profiles', headers=headers)
j = json.loads(r.text)
```

They have given a [guide](https://api.socialbakers.com/#security-and-authentication) to request their API.

How should I make my request using their format?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your headers aren't correct, try running the following code:

```
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1

token = 'mytoken'
headers = { 'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + token }
r = requests.get('https://api.socialbakers.com/0/facebook/profiles', headers=headers)
j = r.json()
```

hope this helps

Comment: I have tried this but same error  "Authorization is not valid."

Comment: In their document it says , "The API is secured with HTTPS. Authentication is made using Basic HTTP Authorization by token and secret. The authorization is sent in the HTTP headers."                                             can you tell me how to pass both in header

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation example; https://api.socialbakers.com/#security-and-authentication
Using Aladin|OpenSesame as token and secret, first we need to use b64encode on them:

```
import requests,base64

encoded_auth_text = base64.b64encode(b'Aladdin'+b':'+b'OpenSesame')
```

Then in order to have that in the header format of the documentation:

```
token = encoded_auth_text.decode('utf-8')
headers = { 'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + token }
print(headers)
```

The header should make sense with the one of the documentation, now we are ready to make the request:

```
response = requests.get(url='https://api.socialbakers.com',
                            headers=headers)

print(response)
```